# configure wildfly logging for multiple path with only different packages and path

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jboss-logging

This is my handler:

```
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="BATCH_HANDLER">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <encoding value="UTF-8"/>
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] - %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <file path="/var/opt/myapp/logs/myapp.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
```

with following:

```
        <logger category="it.mydomain.mybatch" use-parent-handlers="false">
            <handlers>
                <handler name="BATCH_HANDLER"/>
            </handlers>
        </logger>
```

Now I'd like to have configured new handlers like BATCH_HANDLER with only the file path modified, and then a new logger category with different package.

Something like this:

```
        <logger category="it.mydomain.mybatch.aaa">
            <handlers>
                <handler name="BATCH_HANDLER_1"/> <!-- inherits from BATCH_HANDLER except the file path -->
            </handlers>
        </logger>
        <logger category="it.mydomain.mybatch.bbb">
            <handlers>
                <handler name="BATCH_HANDLER_2"/> <!-- inherits from BATCH_HANDLER except the file path -->
            </handlers>
        </logger>
        <logger category="it.mydomain.mybatch.ccc">
            <handlers>
                <handler name="BATCH_HANDLER_3"/> <!-- inherits from BATCH_HANDLER except the file path -->
            </handlers>
        </logger>
```

Is there any way to add handlers that inherit BATCH_HANDLER with only file path changed ?

Comment: You'd have to add a handler for each logger you want going into a different file.

Comment: ok, but do have I to specify all other properties (level, encoding, formatter) over and over again with no chance of inheriting from a base logger?

Comment: Yes. Handlers do not inherit attributes from other handlers. If you want to put it on the base logger you'd need to write a custom handler that can do the routing.

Comment: Sorry, how to achieve the solution you mention above?

Comment: You'd have to write a custom `java.util.logging.Handler` and then add it as a `custom-handler`. So you'd have a single handler which can somehow determine which file it needs to write to.